# in typescript how do I augment the Array interface for numbers only?

Tags: typescript

is there a way to add a method `sum()` to the `Array` interface, but making it work for numbers only? (so that intellisense appears only when the array is `Array<number>`).

Something like this:

```
declare global 
{         
   interface Array<T extends number>
   {                     
      sum(): number;
   }   
}
```

(the above code actually does not work because the compiler expects `Array<T>`)

Answer (score 1):

Not by extending the interface, mainly because in javascript there are no generics and you can't add the **sum** method only in the case the array is of type number.

What you can do however is to create a new class that **extends** Array with the extra method.

It would look something like this:

```js
class NumberArray extends Array<number> {
    sum(): number {
        return super.reduce((previous, current) => previous + current, 0);
    }
}

let x: NumberArray = new NumberArray();
x.sum();
```

It may not be as clean as just adding a new method to the prototype but it's the next best thing.

You can see an example of it in the playground [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20NumberArray%20extends%20Array%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sum()%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20NumberArray%20extends%20Array%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sum()%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20super.reduce((previous%2C%20current)%20%3D%3E%20previous%20%2B%20current%2C%200)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20x%3A%20NumberArray%20%3D%20new%20NumberArray()%3B%0D%0Ax.sum()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A).

Comment: yes, but that needs you use your own class and you can't use it on already existing arrays. My idea was to have a sort of extension method (like in C#). I can actually do it via interface+prototype, the problem is that you can't target `Array<number>` but only the more generic `Array<T>`. I guess the `lib.d.ts` has to be written differently.

Comment: it's not that.. it's just that by the time it reaches javascript the generics get deleted and there is only 1 prototype for Array, you can't add a method on that prototype only for <number>.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended using this solution, which does not provide intellisense but at least is able to catch errors at compile time. The trick is to use the `this:` context for specifying the type of the array:

```
declare global {  
   interface Array<T> {                     
      sum(this: Array<number>): number;
   }   
}

Array.prototype["sum"] = function(this: Array<number>) {
   return this.reduce((previous, current) => previous + current, 0); 
}

["a"].sum() // <- error: string[] is not assignable to number[]
```